# Pandas : finding the average of values within a particular limit in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have imported the first three columns of a .csv file named as *Time, Test 1* and *Test 2* in my python program.

```
import pandas as pd
fields = ['Time', 'Time 1', 'Time 2']
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNAGx.jpg) is the file which I imported in the program.

[image]

How can I make a function which finds the mean/average of the values in the **Test 1** column between a given time limit? The time limits (starting and end values) are to be taken as the parameters in the function.

e.g., I want to find the average of the values in the column **Test 1** from 0.50 seconds to 4.88 seconds. The limits (0.50 and 4.88) would be the function's parameter.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In future, please provide data as text, *not* as an image, *not* as a link. Thank you!

Comment: Understood @jpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) for boolen mask, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and get `mean`:

```
def custom_mean(x,y):
    return df.loc[df['Time'].between(x,y), 'Test 1'].mean()
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.68, 0.94, 1.25, 1.65, 1.88, 2.05, 2.98, 3.45, 3.99, 4.06, 4.68, 4.88, 5.06, 6.0],
                   'Test 1':np.random.randint(10, size=17)})
```

---

```
print (df)
    Test 1  Time
0        3  0.00
1        6  0.25
2        5  0.50
3        4  0.68
4        8  0.94
5        9  1.25
6        1  1.65
7        7  1.88
8        9  2.05
9        6  2.98
10       8  3.45
11       0  3.99
12       5  4.06
13       0  4.68
14       9  4.88
15       6  5.06
16       2  6.00

def custom_mean(x,y):
    return df.loc[df['Time'].between(x,y), 'Test 1'].mean()

print (custom_mean(0.50, 1.0))
5.666666666666667

#verify
print (df.loc[df['Time'].between(0.50, 1.0), 'Test 1'])
2    5
3    4
4    8
Name: Test 1, dtype: int32
```

Comment: When you entered 1.0 as the end limit for the function, did it automatically take the value corresponding to 0.94 seconds? (since 1.0 is not in the column anywhere)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Check bottom of answer, it explain what is exactly seelcted.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Also, if the starting limit is not present in the column, is it going to take the value corresponding to the time just greater than that? For instance, if I enter starting limit as 0.6, will it take the value corresponding to 0.68?

Comment: Yes, sure, you can check it by `print (df.loc[df['Time'].between(0.6, 1.0)])`

Comment: Thanks for the help@jezrael. I'm quite new to Python

Comment: @ArpitSharma - No problem, evry coder starts coding :)

Comment: @ArpitSharma - Some problem? It seems answer was not accepted.

Comment: @ArpitSharma - Thank you. Btw, small advice - in next question is better created small data sample, check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I'll take note of that. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `between` mask and `mean`, `std` function from numpy library.
For example: this line of code will estimate the mean of the `Test 1` while it was taken between time 0.0 and 5.0:

```
np.mean(df[df['Time'].between(0.0, 5.0)]['Test 1'])
```